# MySQL sum with group by for each row

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Cant manage to place a formula on each row, when I add another field I only get 1 row as result, this is the query that returns all the rows with the commented formula:

```
 select x.ext,ifnull(y.rec_out,0) AS rec_out -- , ((rec_out*100)/avg(rec_out))-100 as formula
 from
 (
 select ext from extensiones where grupo = 'rec2'
 )x
 left join 
 (select extensiones.ext as EXTENSION , count(*) AS rec_out, avg(duration) as media
 from extensiones 
 inner join cdr2015 on extensiones.ext = cdr2015.src 
 where grupo = 'rec2'
 AND DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = "2015-03-20"
 group by ext)y on x.ext=y.EXTENSION
```

The formula is an % of the average of count(*).

Result without the formula:

[image: Test]

And With the formula:

[image: test2]

It only does it to 1 row only.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: But without reference to my previous comment !?!